# bind complex json object to knockout dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a complex object being bound to a drop down. [See the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QrvJN/1/).

1. Is this the correct way to bind to a complex object for a drop down menu.
2. The drop down must bind to an initial value(currently working)
3. Changing the selected index in the drop down needs to update the knockout object. This is sort of working. The object is updated when save is called so the drop down's object value is being passed to the Format object. -- However.. This value is not updated in the UI.

I am not sure if it is the mapping that needs some work to make format into an observable. The value of SelectedFormat never seems to change from the first load.

any help on getting this to update the ui and text output of the object would be appreciated.

**Edited:** question to give requirements more clarity

```
code on js fiddle
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QrvJN/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) No its easier than that, just use optionsText point out the member like

```
optionsText: 'Name'
```

Object reference is already implicit the optionsValue so you can skip that, if you want to explicit set it anway you can do the same there and just point to the member optionsValue: $data but its not needed. In other words, this would do http://jsfiddle.net/QrvJN/7/

2) The value and options binding are matched on object reference so if initial value and the list of options do not share references you need to match them yourself. You are doing it a little strange though, I did a binding for this that takes care of the problem http://jsfiddle.net/ewSU2/

3) THis is not needed if you check my solution 2)